# É interessante aprender JSP em 2017?

Tags: java, jsp

Esse semestre na faculdade irei cursar a disciplina de Desenvolvimento de Software para Web e ao estudar a ementa vi que usaremos JSP.

O que me chamou a atenção é o fato da disciplina vir acompanhada de outros temas como XHTML, Tomcat 6 e o uso de uma versão antiga do JDK (versão 5).

Com o que sei até aqui e após uma rápida pesquisa, sabemos que existe o HTML 5, o Tomcat está atualmente na sua versão 8.5 e o Java está caminhando para o JDK 9.

Como claramente a ementa não anda muito atualizada (lamento mais pelos meus colegas de turma que estão começando na área do que por mim), pergunto:

- Aprender JSP em 2017 ainda é relevante?
- É algo presente no mercado e que está em evolução e constante uso ou é algo que vou aprender para esquecer logo em seguida em seis meses?
- Se o JSP já estiver em desuso, quais alternativas utilizar para preencher a lacuna deixada por ele?

Comment: Na verdade eu acho um absurdo curso superior ensinar tecnologia.

Comment: @bigown Concordo com isso, mas julgo que a tecnologia, aqui, é apenas uma ferramenta, não o alvo da disciplina. Também acho que a pergunta pode ser salva.

Comment: É comum ementas de disciplinas estarem desatualizadas (é frequente por exemplo citar a 1a edição de um livro que está em sua terceira ou quarta edição). Não quer dizer que será o que o professor usará nas aulas. Só nunca vi isso especificamente em relação a tecnologias.

Comment: @ramaral acho que todas podem, quando essa for salva, podemos reabrir, no momento ela é baseada em opinião.

Comment: @bigown não me entenda mal, não quis de forma alguma questionar o encerramento.

Comment: @bigown alguma ideia de como melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: @gmsantos não sei, veja se isso ajuda: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5487/101